# Why do I get a IllegalEmptyResponseException

Tags: java, cxf

For my current project I need to implement a SOAP Client calling a remote WS which sends an empty response as its return. The response looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <wsa:Action xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://www.starstandards.org/webservices/2005/10/transport/operations/ProcessMessageResponse</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:RelatesTo xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">[object Object]</wsa:RelatesTo>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <m:ProcessMessageResponse xmlns:m="http://www.starstandards.org/webservices/2005/10/transport"/>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Unfortunately Apache CXF throws an exception:

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Response message did not contain proper response data. Expected: {http://www.starstandards.org/webservices/2005/10/transport}ProcessMessageResponse
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:161)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy76.processMessage(Unknown Source)
[...]
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl$IllegalEmptyResponseException: Response message did not contain proper response data. Expected: {http://www.starstandards.org/webservices/2005/10/transport}ProcessMessageResponse
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.processResult(ClientImpl.java:663)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:532)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:432)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:347)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:305)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:139)
... 3 more
```

For me it looks like that the XML is correct and that CXF is not able to 'see' the ProcessMessageResponse. But maybe I'm just looking too long at this all and I do not see the obviously problem ...

Currently used CXF-Version: 3.1.18
I also tried it with 3.2.14 but ends in the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the exact solution, but you can suppress the exception as a WA.

Comment: Yes, that is what I currently do. But it looks ugly and is not great... However, it is indeed better to have a workaround as no functional code.